# how to validate some of the fields out of all required field in mongoose schema during save?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

How to validate some of the fields out of all required field in mongoose schema during save or update my code is some thing like this...

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
first_name      : { type: String, required: 'First name is required!'},
last_name       : { type: String, required: 'Last name is required!'},
user_name       : { type: String, required: 'Product cost is required!', unique: true},
email           : { type: String, required: 'E-mail cost is required!', unique: true},
password        : { type: String, required: 'Password is required!'},
country         : { type: String, required: 'country is required!'}, 
address         : { type: String, required: 'address is required!'},
phone           : { type: Number, required: 'Phone number is required!'},
profile_image   : { type: String },
create_date     : { type: Date }
```

});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

And i want to save only the fields below. others will be saved during update profile.

```
var newUser     = new User({
        first_name              : req.body.first_name,
        last_name               : req.body.last_name,
        user_name               : req.body.user_name,
        email                   : req.body.email,
        password                : req.body.password,
        password_confirmation   : req.body.password_confirmation,           
        create_date             : d.toLocaleString()
    });
    newUser.save(function(err) {
        if (err){
            //console.log(err);
            components.Error.normalize(err,function(returnData) {
                //console.log(returnData);
                res.status(207).json({status:0,error:returnData});
            });
        }else{
            res.status(200).json({status:1,message:'User saved successfully'});
        }            
    });
```

it returns error of all required fields that i don't want to save during creation, but those are also required field for profile update part.

Comment: Well you have marked them as "required", which should be very self explanatory. If they really are **not** "required", then simply don't mark them as such.

Comment: Hello Seven, Thanks for your reply. But the problem is i need the server side required validation when i am going to update those information. in initial stage i am taking all the basic required information from client. once done and the user login to the account then during edit there profile i need they must enter those fields thats why i have added those as required. is there any other way to achieve my requirement?

Comment: You are still missing that "required" means it **must** be there. There are no exceptions to this.

Comment: You may add `{ validateBeforeSave: false }` in the `newUser.save({ validateBeforeSave: false }, function(err) {`, which will ignore all validation before save it. However, it cannot do the partial validation...

Comment: if i remove the required from mongoose schema for those validation, then how can i manage the server side validation? is there any other way?

Comment: Thanks zangw for the reply. But i need some server side validation. if i make it false then i have to apply some custom validation in server side. is there any other way to apply validation in nodejs except mongoose validation?

Comment: Have a look at custom validation http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html